# Chris Banes' Android-PullToRefresh java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.R$id.pull_to_refresh_sub_text

Tags: android, gridview, refresh

I'm trying to use https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/. I followed the example but got the error 
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.R$id.pull_to_refresh_sub_text

This is my grid:

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshGridView
  xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.abc.myproject"
  android:id="@+id/gv_image"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:listSelector="#00000000"
  android:padding="4dp"
  android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
  android:verticalSpacing="4dp"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:numColumns="3"
  android:columnWidth="128px"
  android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
  ptr:ptrMode="pullDownFromTop"
  ptr:ptrDrawable="@drawable/android" />
```

When I run I have the above exception. I added the PullToRefresh as another project in the workspace and make it my project's library. I also added the Jar file. I think the error is because the line 
    xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.abc.myproject"?

I traced the code and the line that caused the exception is in LoadingLayout.java:
mSubHeaderText = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.pull_to_refresh_sub_text);

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I have also the same problem, did you able to solve out your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android SDK Tools r17 adds support for custom views with custom attributes in libraries. Layouts using custom attributes must use the namespace URI:

`http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto`

instead of the URI that includes the app package name. This URI is replaced with the app specific one at build time.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue,

What I did to fix it was to move the reference to the library from the bottom to the top of the list. I think there was something I was referencing that was conflicting with the generation of the IDs in `R.java`.

You can do a search in `R.java` for `pull_to_refresh_sub_text` to make sure it has generated it properly.